# Local Git multi users issue

Tags: git

I have a local git version control installed on RedHat 8 server, and when I run `git add *` it asks me to provide the `sudo` permissions which is `sudo git add *` and this makes the add run with the root for me and all the other team do the same.

So, when I run `git log` it provides me with the list of changes however the **changer for all changes is the root**. How to make each user run with its own credentials?

Comment: It's unclear from reading your question _why_ you have to run `git` with `sudo`. Are you _sharing_ a cloned repository?

Comment: Hello @Kusalananda
thanks for your reply.

the `git commit -m`  command won't run without `sudo` and gives an error of `permission denied`,  do you have any idea to run it with normal privilege?

Comment: Yes, make sure you have access to all the files that you are committing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, what's happening here is that you try to use `git` on files that aren't accessible by your (non-root) user.

That might be because the actual source files don't belong to you, or because the .git directory doesn't – which definitely happens once someone (you maybe?) used `sudo git`.

**Git is not meant for multi-user repo checkouts.** You're simply using git in a way that it was *specifically designed to **not** be used in*¹.

You **must stop** using git the way you're currently using it. It will lead to someone finally breaking something, the repo will need to be repaired. And that's the best case – I've seen people do exactly what you're doing, and they ended up irreparably separating the state that's tracked from the checkout, and loss of source code was the result. All because they insisted on using `sudo` and a single shared repo, instead of taking the 30 seconds to actually clone that repo, work locally and `git push` their changes upstream.

Git's design is such that each user can have its own, independent, 100% owned by them, clone of the "upstream" repo. Each user should work on their own copy. *There is no shared copy*.

If you need something like "I make changes and they need to take effect on a shared infrastructure", then you do something like this:

1. Somewhere on a server, you set up a new user (that user is commonly just called `git`), and you give all the team members SSH access by adding their SSH public keys to the user's `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys`.
2. You create a *bare* repo in the home directory of that new user, `git init --bare mygitproject`.
3. You add a script as `post-receive` [git hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#post-receive). Git will automatically execute that script the moment someone pushes something to that repo.
   3.1. In that script, you can, for example, do something like "if that push was to the `main` branch of the repo, check out all the files into a target directory." For example, `git --work-tree=/etc/apache2 checkout main` would be something you find in that script if you wanted to keep your apache2 configuration in git.
4. All the individual users use `git clone` to get their **local** and **own** copy of the repo. They work on there, `git commit` and finally `git push`. No root / `sudo` involved at all!

Of course, what the above does is implement a tiny "continuous deployment" (CD) environment. More might software exists that can do all this for you, including managing users that can push and so on. [Forgejo](https://forgejo.org/) is one of such.

---

¹ Git supports what is called *shared repos*, indeed, with a long list of caveats, and a strict requirement that you understand the ramification of the underlying user permission issues. The way you describe your error, that really is not the scenario you and your colleagues are in; I'd very strongly recommend against using that option, and if asked about usage details, will not elaborate.
The official git manual puts it like this (my paraphrasing):

> You *can* do that, which will be especially appealing if you're used to 41 year old revision control system architecture and slow at learning new things. But *not* doing that only has advantages, including avoiding that someone accidentally breaks everything.